# alpha sort the list which has same integer values and should be in ascending order

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart

The `Dart` list should be sorted alphabetical based on the same integer value inside the element object. If the integer has same values those related strings should be in aplhabetical and ascending order

Here is the list.

```
 List<People> items = [
  People( 10 ,  'a' ) ,
  People(  5 ,  'c' ),
  People( 15 ,  'b' ),
  People(  15 ,  'a' ),
  People(  5 , 'k' ),
  People(  10 , 'd' ) 
  People(   7, 'c' )];
```

Expected result :

```
 List<People> items = [
  People( 5 ,  'c' ) ,
  People(  5 ,  'k' ),
  People( 7 ,  'c' ),
  People(  10 ,  'a' ),
  People(  10 , 'k' ),
  People(  15 , 'a' ) 
  People(   15, 'd' )];
```

Comment: Why the Java tag if this is a Dart question?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the expected output for the provided input should be :

```
[People(5, 'c', People(5, 'k', People(7, 'c', People(10, 'a', People(10, 'd', People(15, 'a', People(15, 'b']
```

Try the below code to get the desired output:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<People> people = new ArrayList<>();
        people.add(new People(10, 'a'));
        people.add(new People(5, 'c'));
        people.add(new People(15, 'b'));
        people.add(new People(15, 'a'));
        people.add(new People(5, 'k'));
        people.add(new People(10, 'd'));
        people.add(new People(7, 'c'));
        System.out.println(people);
        Collections.sort(people, Comparator.comparing(People::getNumber)
                .thenComparing(People::getaChar));
        System.out.println(people);
    }

}

class People {
    private int number;
    private char aChar;

    public People(int number, char aChar) {
        this.number = number;
        this.aChar = aChar;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public char getaChar() {
        return aChar;
    }

    public void setaChar(char aChar) {
        this.aChar = aChar;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "People("  + number +
                ", '" + aChar +
                "'";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In dart language, you can sort it like below code example.

```dart
void main() {
  final items = [ People( 10 , 'a' ) , People( 5 , 'c' ), People( 15 , 'b' ), People( 15 , 'a' ), People( 5 , 'k' ), People( 10 , 'd' ), People( 7, 'c' )];
  items.sort((a,b)=> a.string.compareTo(b.string));
  items.forEach((item)=> print(item.string + item.value.toString()));
}

class People{
   final int value;
   final String string;
  
   People(this.value, this.string);
}
```

output;

```dart
a10
a15
b15
c5
c7
d10
k5
```

Comment: i need a sorting, if integers are same that related strings should be in alphabetical order and the interger values should be ascending order

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete example of sorting your list

**Main**

```
void main() {
  //List of items
  List<People> items = [
    People(10, 'a'),
    People(5, 'k'),
    People(5, 'c'),
    People(15, 'b'),
    People(15, 'a'),
    People(10, 'd'),
    People(7, 'c')
  ];
  
  //Printing List before sorting
  Methods.printList(items, "\n\nBefore\n\n");
 
  //Step 01 : Sort the List according to alpha order
  items.sort((a, b) => a.string.compareTo(b.string));
  
  //Step 02 : Sort the list according to num order
  items.sort(Methods.sortMyListNumOrder);

  //Printing List after sorting
  Methods.printList(items, "\n\nAfter\n\n");
}
```

***Method class***

```
//class of Methods i.e printing and sorting
class Methods{
  static void printList(List<People> items, String value){
   print(value);
   for(var item in items){
      print("People(${item.integer} , ${item.string})");
    }
  }
  static int sortMyListNumOrder(People first, People second) {
    final int firstValue = first.integer;
    final int secondValue = second.integer;
    if (firstValue < secondValue) {
      return -1;
    } else if (firstValue > secondValue) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

***People Class***

```
//People class
class People {
  final String string;
  final int integer;

  People(
    this.integer,
    this.string,
  );
}
```