# List sorting, if integers are same that related strings should be in alphabetical order and the interger values should be ascending order

Tags: flutter, sorting, dart, alphabetical

The Dart list should be sorted alphabetical based on the same integer value inside the element object. If the integer has same values those related strings should be in aplhabetical and ascending order

Here is the list.

List items = [ People( 10 , 'a' ) , People( 5 , 'c' ), People( 15 , 'b' ), People( 15 , 'a' ), People( 5 , 'k' ), People( 10 , 'd' ) People( 7, 'c' )];

Expected result :

List items = [ People( 5 , 'c' ) , People( 5 , 'k' ), People( 7 , 'c' ), People( 10 , 'a' ), People( 10 , 'k' ), People( 15 , 'a' ) People( 15, 'd' )];

Comment: does `People` class implement `Comparable`? if so, post it, `List.sort` docs say: *"The default List implementations use Comparable.compare if compare is omitted."*

Comment: No didn't implememted Comparable.

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/Comparable-class.html - they say: *"Interface used by types that have an intrinsic ordering.

The compareTo operation defines a total ordering of objects, which can be used for ordering and sorting.

The Comparable interface should be used for the natural ordering of a type. If a type can be ordered in more than one way, and none of them is the obvious natural ordering, then it might be better not to use the Comparable interface, and to provide separate Comparators instead."*

Comment: You already asked this in https://stackoverflow.com/q/70458967/, which I marked as a duplicate of [Sort a list of objects in Flutter (Dart) by property value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53547997/).   If you want to ask a good question, you should explain why those answers aren't sufficient (note that [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61673246/) (disclosure: mine) specifically addresses how to sort by multiple properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need of the double sorting suggested by Jahidul Islam. You just need to make a compare method which compares the name in case the number is the same. So something like this:

```
void main() {
  final items = [
    People(10, 'a'),
    People(5, 'c'),
    People(15, 'b'),
    People(15, 'a'),
    People(5, 'k'),
    People(10, 'd'),
    People(7, 'c'),
  ];

  print(items);
  // [People(10,'a'), People(5,'c'), People(15,'b'), People(15,'a'), People(5,'k'), People(10,'d'), People(7,'c')]

  items.sort((p1, p2) {
    final compareAge = p1.age.compareTo(p2.age);

    if (compareAge != 0) {
      return compareAge;
    } else {
      return p1.name.compareTo(p2.name);
    }
  });

  print(items);
  // [People(5,'c'), People(5,'k'), People(7,'c'), People(10,'a'), People(10,'d'), People(15,'a'), People(15,'b')]
}

class People {
  final int age;
  final String name;

  People(this.age, this.name);

  @override
  String toString() => "People($age,'$name')";
}
```